# OpenGL color depth buffer

Tags: opengl

I have simple studyng project representing some space star's system. I have a star and several planets with moons rotating around the star. I'm using depth buffer, but planets are always in front of the star even if planet should be shadowed by the star. What can be the issue reason?

```
void drawPlanet(float orbitRadius, float planetRadius, float daysInYear, float hoursInDay){
    static float year = 0;
    static float days = 0;
    static float hours = 0;
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(year, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(orbitRadius, 0 ,0);
    glRotatef(days, 1, 2, 0);
    glutWireSphere(planetRadius, 20, 16);
    drawLuna(0.3, 0.1, 30, 15);
    glPopMatrix();
    hours++;
    days = hours/hoursInDay;
    year=days/daysInYear;
}

void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,5, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 0);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.647059, 0.00);
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 20, 16);

    glColor3b(197, 96, 63);
    drawPlanet(2, 0.2, 50, 12);
    drawPlanet(1, 0.15, 30, 15);

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ....
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` has no effect if there's no OpenGL context. GLUT creates the OpenGL context only after `glutCreateWindow` has been called.

As a general rule you should not call `glEnable` outside of the display function. You will also have to clear the depth buffer, so make this

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```